# Batch file to recursively loop through subfolders and remove files upon condition

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to automate a little tedious process I have to go through while updating files on my server. I have a content folder, with a lot of subfolders, each potentially containing some files. Some files have a compressed version (ending with .bz2). So a folder could have something like:

```
sound1.wav
sound1.wav.bz2
sound2.wav
texture1.tex
texture2.tex
texture2.tex.bz2
```

What I want to do is remove every file (somewhere in the content folder) that has an equivalent compressed file. Meaning in the above example I just want 'texture2.tex' and 'sound1.wav' removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /r %%f in (*) do if exist "%%f.bz2" del "%%f"
```

Or, at the command line instead of in a batch file:

```
for /r %f in (*) do if exist "%f.bz2" del "%f"
```

Comment: Instead of deleting, the console outputs the file paths for me.

Answer (score -2):

Little mistake. It should be:

```
for /r %%f in (*.bz2) do if exist "%%f" del "%%f"
```

Or, at the command line instead of in a batch file:

```
for /r %f in (*.bz2) do if exist "%f" del "%f"
```